# How to transform SQL Table Data into CSV using Java/ESB?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, csv

I have requirement to take data dump of certain tables (sql server) and convert into CSV format. I can write Java program which can read table data and then convert into CVS format. but my question is, is there ready to use transformation framework available in Java/Java EE or JBoss ESB?

I know Smook Transformation has various capabilities but not sure whether it can convert SQL table data into CSV

If anybody has done previously using ESB or any other pattern then please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use Java?  Or could SQL Server utilities be used?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use SQL server tool, [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) should be simplest way to copy data from a database table to .csv file. Here is an example to use BCP

```
BCP <YourTable> out c:\temp\TableName.csv -c -t, -T –S<servername>
```